# Android MVP - how to work with logic dependent on Android classes?

Tags: android, architecture, mvp

I'm working on an existing app, migrating it towards the `MVP` architecture. In one of the `RecyclerView.Adapter`s, there's quite a lot of logic in regards to how a header `View` should look like. According to the `MVP` architecture, such logic should be moved to the `Presenter` and the presenter should use the `View` to display *things*. Also, I've read quite a lot about how if you have `Android` classes in your presenter - that basically indicates that something went wrong.

So my thoughts so far are to create a `Presenter` for the `ViewHolder` when the `ViewHolder` (also the `View` from the `MVP` standpoint) is created and to move my logic there. Howeverm the problem I'm having is that the logic is based on `Android` classes such as `Paint`, `Rect`, `Spannable` and so on.

So how do I solve this problem in the cleanest way possible? Do I move all the logic to the `View`? Or should I keep the logic in my `Presenter`, but move only the calculations related to the specific `Android` objects to the `View`? As an example that would look something like that:

in presenter:

```
double textLines = mView.getTextLines(text, 0 , text.length());
```

in view:

```
Paint paint = mTextView.getPaint();
Rect bounds = new Rect();
paint.getTextBounds(text, start, end, bounds);
double parentWidth = parentView.getWidth() - parentView.getPaddingLeft() - parentView
            .getPaddingRight();
return Math.ceil((double) bounds.width() / parentWidth);
```

Or is there another better way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Every piece of code that depends on Android classes should be kept on the view implementation (Activiy, Fragment, ViewHolder etc) - the view should be as dumb as possible. I think you don't need a presenter for the ViewHolder, as it usually should not have logic.

If you have unit tests (and you should), the process becomes easier to grasp because you will be forced to move Android dependent classes to somewhere else in order to be able to test it.

For example, a real case scenario I have with RecyclerView is something like this: one view interface for the Activity, one view interface for the ViewHolder, one presenter for the Adapter and one presenter for the Activity. The following is a partial, non compilable example just for demonstration, where you can see the separation of concerns between the layers.

So, in your case, the approach is correct: the view interface just have a method that returns a string "from somewhere", while in the real android view you use the actual classes and methods from the Android API to retrieve the requested data.

My example is below.

```
// Definitions for the event adapter stuff
public interface EventAdapterContract {
    interface View {
        void onFetchEventsFailed(String reason);
        void notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    interface Presenter {
        void getItemViewType(int position);
        void getItemCount();
        void bindEventRow(int position, ViewHolder holder, int backgroundColor);
    }

    interface ViewHolder {
        void setTitle(String value);
        void setHour(String value);
        void setBackgroundColor(int color);
    }
}

// Adapter presenter implementation. Again, partial code for simplicity
public class EventAdapterPresenter implements EventAdapterContract.Presenter {
    private final EventAdapterContract.View view;
    private final List<Event> events;

    static int VIEW_FINISHED = 0;
    static int VIEW_pending = 0;

    public EventAdapterPresenter(EventAdapterContract.View view, EventAPI api) {
        this.view = view;
        this.events = new ArrayList<>();

        // EventAPI is an interface (Retrofit in this case), which can
        // also be tested with plain junit
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return events.size();
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemViewType(int position) {
        Event item = events.get(position);
        return item.isFinished() ? VIEW_FINISHED : VIEW_PENDING;
    }

    @Override
    public void bindEventRow(int position, EventAdapterContract.ViewHolder holder, int backgroundColor) {
        Event event = events.get(position);
        holder.setTitle(event.getTitle());
        holder.setHour(String.format("Event time: %s", event.getStartTime()));
        holder.setBackgroundColor(backgroundColor);
    }
}



// The adapter itself. Please mind that this is a partial
// piece of code just for the sake of demonstration, 
// I ommited several parts to keep it simple
public class EventAdapter 
    extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerView.ViewHolder> 
    implements EventAdapterContract.View {

    private EventAdapterContract.Presenter presenter;

    public class EventAdapter(Contex context) {
        // Regular adapter contructor
        // ...
        presenter = new EventAdapterPresenter(this, someImplOfEventApi);
    }

    @Override
    public void onFetchEventsFailed(String reason) {
        // Show an AlertDialog
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemViewType(int position) {
        return presenter.getItemViewType(position);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        int backgroundColor = ContextCompat.getColor(context, R.color.colorEventPending);
        presenter.bindEventRow(position, holder, backgroundColor);
    }
}

public class EventRowViewHolder 
    extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder
    implements View.OnClickListener, EventAdapterContract.ViewHolder.Row {

    private TextView title;
    private TextView hour;

    public EventRowViewHolder(View view) {
        super(view);
        // init widgets etc...
        view.setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void setTitle(String value) {
        title.setText(value);
    }

    @Override
    public void setHour(String value) {
        hour.setText(value);
    }

    @Override
    public void setBackgroundColor(int color) {
        this.itemView.setBackgroundColor(color);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        EventBus.getDefault().post(new OpenEventDetailsMessage(orderId));
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the confirmation. Yeah I agree that the `ViewHolder` itself doesn't need logic/ presenter. Logic is for binding, i.e for the `Adapter`. Thanks again, very helpful